# How to get the current time to an existing date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, time, formatting

I'm trying to add the current time to an existing date but I'm not sure how to do it.
I'm importing stuff into a Postgres database and need a ISO string to update the "updatedAt" column, the imported stuff only has a date like this tho: "2022-03-15", no time.

How would I add the time to this and turn it into a proper ISO string for my database?

```
const date = new Date('2022-03-15')
const iso = date.toISOSTring() // how to add the current time?
-
Should look like this: "2022-03-15 09:36:54.292613"
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: Thanks for helping, and sorry for not responding until now, I got rid of the date check for now, it was just a performance optimization that is not too important atm!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the time units into `date` from the current date-time i.e. `new Date()`.

```js
const date = new Date("2022-03-15");
const now = new Date();
date.setHours(now.getHours());
date.setMinutes(now.getMinutes());
date.setSeconds(now.getSeconds());
date.setMilliseconds(now.getMilliseconds());
console.log(date.toISOString());
console.log(date.toISOString().replace("T", " ").replace("Z", " "));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use dayJs and add the time that you need, https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string

```
dayjs('2018-04-04T16:00:00.000Z')
dayjs('2018-04-13 19:18:17.040+02:00')
dayjs('2018-04-13 19:18')
```